# C++ How send multiple values to two upper superclass?

Tags: c++

First of all think about a factory system. i create a Date class to hold person's birthday and  initial date to work.e.g
and i have person class which holds information about person name, surname etc.
and finally have a department class and i want to initialize all information about Person and department id and department name(name, surname..,birthday, initial to work date ). i created an array in the type of Person in department header file. My problem is that how can i write deparment construct to initialize all attributes. no problem with the name, surname... but Date Class requires 3 parameter. how can i send there parameter together with the other parameters from Department class?

```
class Date {
int gun,ay,yil;

public:

int getDay()const;
int getMonth()const;
int getYear()const;

void set_Day(int);
void setMonth(int);
void setYear(int);

    Date();
    Date(int,int,int);
    virtual ~Date();

}
class Deparment
{


    int     bolumId;
    string  bolumName;
    static const int maxkisi = 10;
    Person *PersonArray = new Person[maxkisi];
    static int counter;
    Date datex,datey;
    public:
    int     getBolumId()const;
    string  getBolumName()const;
    int     getTemelMaas()const;
    Person    getPersonArray()const;

    void setBolumId(int);
    void setBolumName(string);
    void setKisiarray(string,string,int,int);

        Bolum();
        Bolum(string,string,int,Date,Date,int,string);
        virtual ~Bolum();

}
```

Comment: i m trying to upload other classes but giving me error !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about doing it:

- Take a `Date` object in the constructor of your class, or
- Take the date's parameters in the constructor of your class.

Each of the two approaches has its pluses and minuses:

The first approach hides the parameters taken by `Date` from the caller, so the caller can construct the `Date` in any way he wishes:

```
Person(const string& _name, const string& _surname, const Date& _dob)
:   name(_name), surname(_surname), dob(_dob) {
}
```

The second approach lets you hide the `Date` from the caller, which is good if your class does *not* expose `Date` as an externally visible attribute. In other words, you can hide the fact that your class uses `Date`, letting you switch away from that implementation if you need to do so in the future.

```
Person::Person(const string& _name, const string& _surname, int dd, int mm, int yy)
:  name(_name), surname(_surname), dob(Date(mm, dd, yy) {
}
```

Comment: no problem setting up from the person class my problem is that i want initialize from department class (date<<person<<department) as i said i have person array in the department class ??

Comment: @firehorse All I can see is `Date`, so I cannot tell what's the difference between initializing a `Date` from `Person` vs. from `Department`.

Comment: thanx a lot for your help. i will try to upload other classes for clear discussion..

Comment: @firehorse So that's the approach #1, right? You can change `Date` parameters to `const Date&` parameter, and keep everything else the same.